# Add blur/gradient to image outside of mask in python

Tags: python, image, opencv, image-processing, python-imaging-library

I have a bounding box whose coordinates are given by (x, y, w, h) where x and y are top-left coordinates of the box. I'd like to apply a blur or gradient outside the box. How would I create a mask using the coordinates above and apply this effect outside the mask with either PIL or cv2 similar to the image below?

[image: img]

Comment: Copy the part you don't want to blur to a new image, blur the original, copy the unblurred into the burred.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Here is an example, I think that should be helpful to adapt it to your program.

```
import cv2
original = cv2.imread("spidy.png", 3)
blurred = cv2.GaussianBlur(original, (25,25), 0)

original[0:500, 0:500] = blurred[0:500, 0:500]
cv2.imwrite('cvBlurredOutput.jpg', original)
```

1) First read Image

2) Blur it, the parameter `(25,25)` is the blur kernel, basically the `width/height` of your "blur Brush"

3) finally copy the `region of interest` from the `blurred` to the `original`

Comment: Thank you, this is much simpler than what I've found so far.

Comment: If I wanted to apply gaussian blur like a gradient (smaller brush size increasing radially), any idea on how would I do that?

Comment: Depends on what kind of `falloff` you want. If it's linear you can basically create the value `[0:255]` going from black to white and use this as a multiplier.